# Is there a power function for tensors in pytorch?

Tags: numpy, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

Is there an equivalent of `numpy.power` in pytorch?

The function basically raises each element in the first tensor to the power represented in each corresponding element in the second tensor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`torch.pow`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.pow).

As mentioned by [@Szymon Maszke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63110621/is-there-a-power-function-for-tensors-in-pytorch/63111011#comment111603364_63111011), you can also use `**` operator:

```py
y = torch.pow(x, y)
# the same as
y = x ** y
# and also the same as
y = x.pow(y)
```

where `y` can be a scalar or a tensor with shape [broadcastable](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.12/notes/broadcasting.html) to `x`'s shape.

Comment: `torch.pow` only applies a scalar power to all the elements. `numpy.power` applies element-wise power between two tensors.

Comment: @Light `torch.pow(tensor1, tensor2)` works element-wise. You could also use `tensor1 ** tensor2` or `tensor1.pow(tensor2)`.